# How do I apply my model to a new dataset in WEKA?

Tags: data-mining, weka, prediction

I have created a new prediction model based on a dataset that was given to me. It predicts a nominal (binary) class attribute (positive/negative) based on a number of numerical attributes.

Now I have been asked to use this prediction model to predict classes for a new dataset. This dataset has all the same attributes except for the class column, which does not exist yet. How do I apply my model to this new data? I have tried adding an empty class column to my new dataset and then doing the following:

- Simply loading the new dataset in WEKA's explorer and loading the model. It tells me there is no training data.
- Opening my training set in WEKA's explorer and then opening my training model, then choosing my new data as a 'supplied test set'. It runs but does not output any predictions.

I should note that the model works fine when testing on the training data for cross validation. It also works fine with a subset of the training data I separated ages ago for test/eval use. I think it may be a problem with how I am adding a new class column, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making predictions, Weka requires the two datasets, training and the one for making predictions, to have the exact same structure, down to the order of labels. That also means, that you need to have a class attribute with the correct labels present. In terms of values for your class attribute, simply use the missing value (denoted by a question mark).

See the FAQ [How do i make predictions with a trained model?](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/how_do_i_make_predictions_with_a_trained_model/) on the Weka wiki for more information on how to make predictions.